# Ear Clipping Traingulation Algorithm in Meatl

Tags: ios, geometry, metal, triangulation

I am doing ear clipping algorithm in Metal. My Points for Triangulation is as this picture below[image]

I need to traingulate inside the Area.  I got the following results below [image]

The Algorithm I used is Ear Clipping. But here my traingles are overlapping. What I did was I have a 2D points Array of Picture 1 .

I find Reflex angle of a point using its previous and Next Point using cosine rule. and from 360 subtracting the value from it. If it is reflex.

I think the Problem is there. because for me every point showed me as reflex angle. Can anybody suggest how to find reflex angle in Ear Clipping Algorithm

Comment: Ear clipping (and more generally triangulation) is defined for *simple* polygons. Yours is not. Make it simple first by detecting the self-intersections.

Comment: And regarding the reflex angles: You cannot distinguish angles < 180° and >180° with the cosine (just look at the function plot). You need a proper orientation of your polygon and calculate the proper orientation of the angle (e.g. using atan2 with the cosine from the dot product and the sine from the cross product).